# Silex and Doctrine ORM

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

I am trying to use Silex together with Doctrine ORM (not just DBAL) but I am unable to get the configuration correct.

composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.1",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.1",
    "symfony/form": "~2.1",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/form": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/translation": "~2.1",
    "symfony/config": "2.2.*",
    "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "1.0.*@dev"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "Entities": "src/"
    }  
  }
}
```

bootstrap.php located in my project root folder

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once __DIR__ ."/vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/Entities"), $isDevMode);

$params = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/development.sqlite',
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($params, $config);
```

cli-config.php also located inside the root folder

```
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($entityManager->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($entityManager)
));
```

Customer.php entity located inside src/Entities

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="customers")
 **/
class Customer {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $name;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I am able to run commands like `php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` and have it generate a table called customs just as it should. But how do I load that entity inside my Silex application

Here is my index.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
$app['config'] = function () {
    $config = Yaml::parse(__DIR__ .'/../config.yml');

    return $config;
};

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'dns.options' => $app['config']['database']['development']
));
$app->register(new Dflydev\Silex\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider, array(
    'orm.em.options' => array(
        'mappings' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'annotation',
                'path' => __DIR__ .'/src/Entities',
            )
        )
    ),
));
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $customer = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('Customer');

return '<pre>'. $customer->getName() .'</pre>';
});
```

The result when loading the localhost inside my browser

```
Warning: class_parents() [function.class-parents]: Class Customer does not exist and could not be loaded in /Users/me/Documents/project/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 40
```

**UPDATE**
I am not sure this is the correct way to solve this issue, but by using the following approach the problem got solved and I can now use my entities in Silex

```
$app['em'] = function ($app) {
    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/Entities"), true);
    $params = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
      'path' => __DIR__ . '/../development.sqlite',
    );
    $entityManager = EntityManager::create($params, $config);

    return $entityManager;
};
```

I used the dependency approach because that way I can use $app['config'] to store DB information and other environment specific configurations.

```
$customer = new \Entities\Customer();
$customer->setName('Multi Corp '. uniqid());

$app['em']->persist($customer);
$app['em']->flush();
```

Answer (score 3):

I presume your doctrine Entity mappings reside under "/src/Entities" in the namespace `\Entities`. With your autoloader directive they should be accessible as `\Entities\MyMappingCls`.

Your problem seems to be that you don't give the fq-name of the mapping class when getting the repository. You need to give a string that can be resolved by the autoloader. Please try:

```
$app['orm.em']->getRepository('Entities\Customer');
```

You can also try to run `orm:generate-proxies` as they are only generated on the fly in debug mode (not so sure this is relevant).

hth